# My HTML file isn't connecting to my CSS file. Why?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am not being able to connect my CSS to my HTML file. I put the code below in my head at the top of my HTML file. I used the code on this website to connect my CSS to HTML: http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

This is my HTML file so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>

<body id="whole-background">
<h1>Akhil Sharma</h1>

<p>Official Website</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css:

```
#whole-background
{
background-color: #0099FF;
}
```

Someone please tell how I can fix this problem.

Comment: That looks okay. Is your theme.css in the same directory as the HTML file?

Comment: The file css is in the same directory of the file html?

Comment: What's the directory structure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by directory structure, but I guess it is this:

Comment: @ErBnAcharya 2 `body` tag, WHAT?

Comment: Worked well with IE, Opera, FireFox and Chrome. Did you try different browsers?

Comment: I am talking about google chrome. and the structure i think is C:\Documents and Settings\Akhil.AKHIL-HP\My Documents\aswebpage

Comment: If you look at the browser's console, is the CSS file being loaded? If you replace the index.html (or whatever the HTML file's name is) with theme.css in the browser's address bar does the CSS file open in the browser?

Comment: chrome says the webpage is not available. when i replace index.html with theme.css

Comment: So the file is *not* in the same directory.

Comment: how can I make it in the same directory_

Comment: If you don't know how to move files in Windows, perhaps you should ask http://superuser.com.

Comment: I do, but it already is? SO I don\t understand what everyone talking about

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29668/discussion-between-user1594853-and-juhana)

Comment: According http://validator.w3.org/?doctype=HTML5 you might need to add a `<title>title</title>` ... just an idea

Answer (score 1):

Save a file called  *theme.css* in the same directory of the html page, with your css rules

```
#whole-background
{
background-color: #0099FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, self close your link tag, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
```

Next, make sure that your stylesheet (theme.css) is located in the same folder as the html file you are saving.  It it is elsewhere, such as in a subfolder called "styles" then you would have to edit the path like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/theme.css" />
```

Comment: Also if the page is in another folder than `../` will be useful too

Comment: I think you forgot to self-close the tag. Not that it matters in HTML5.

Comment: Whoops, how embarrassing.  Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

To solve these kinds of Problems I highly recommend using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/%E2%80%8E). While you are using firebug you can debug all kinds of problems. One major problem, why is my CSS not linked, or is it and I didnt code it correctly. You can open firebug. Select the CSS TAB

[image]

And see all CSS that are linked. You can also look inside console to see what error codes come up, they are very detailed and save you allot of time.

[image]

This is to help you with figuring out these kinds of problems. You dont necessarily have to use link btw.

```
<style type="text/css" src="theme.css"></style>
```

Works just as good.